# How to get remaining duration of downloading file

Tags: java, android, time

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




    // button to show progress Dialog
    Button btnShowProgress;

    // progress dialog
    ProgressDialog proDaiog;


    //File url to download
    private static String url = "http://rvo/file/Ardu_Vid.mp4";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // show progress bar button
        btnShowProgress = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        btnShowProgress.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DownloadFile().execute(url);
                //   running = true;
                //   runTimer();

            }
        });

    } // end onCreate

    private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            proDaiog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

            //Set progress dialog title
            proDaiog.setTitle("Downloading...");

            //set progress dialog message
            proDaiog.setMessage("");
            proDaiog.setIndeterminate(false);
            proDaiog.setMax(100);
            proDaiog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);


            proDaiog.show();

        }


        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... Url) {
            try {
                URL url = new URL(Url[0]);
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                //Detect File Length
                int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

                //Locate Storage Location
                String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

                //Downloading File
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());

                //Save the Download File
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filePath + "/" + "Ardu_Vid.mp4");

                byte data[] = new byte[fileLength];
                long total = 0;
                int count;
                int s = 1;
                //  Long startTime = System.nanoTime();
                //  Log.e("Time-",""+startTime);
//                Long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
                int sec = 0;

                while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {

                    long Start_Timee = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    //long seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(Start_Timee);


                    total += count;
                    output.write(data, 0, count);

                    //publish the progress
                    publishProgress((int) (total * 100 / fileLength));

                /************ Get Duration of Downloading ***************/

                    Long End_Timee = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Log.e("Time_End", "" + End_Timee);

                    long seccc = (End_Timee - Start_Timee);
                    Log.e("estimate ",""+seccc);

                    int seconds = (int) (seccc / 1000) % 60 ;
                    int minutes = (int) ((seccc / (1000*60)) % 60);
                    Log.e("elapse",""+minutes+":"+seconds);



                }// end while

                //close connection
                output.flush();
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
            proDaiog.setProgress(progress[0].intValue());
            Log.i("proDaiog.setProgress", "" + progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            proDaiog.dismiss();
        }
    } // end Asyc
```

I want to get Remaining duration of downloading File Means If you use Idm you was see left time during downloading  i want show same functionality in my app but i stuck on this functionality i completed whole app but i 'm stuck only Remaining  duration please help

Comment: looks like you are downloading the entire file length into a byte[] at once. You should download it by parts, using some small buffer to be able to calculate ETA

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to get you going:

1. Your code knows about the file size
2. Your code can know how many bytes were downloaded so far; and how much time that took

Using that information it should be pretty straightforward to compute an **estimate** about the remaining time.

In other words: simply compute the current download rate X (you want to make sure to wait some time before doing that; in order to use somehow "reliable" (aka stable) numbers). Then compute how much time it should take to download the remaining number of bytes Y ... given X.

Example: assume you want to download a file that has 100 MB.

After 1 minute, you check and find that you downloaded 10 MB so far.
So, your observation is: "download speed is about 10MB per minute".

That means: if that speed doesn't change too much, you will need about 9 more minutes for the remaining 90 MB.

Of course, that is just an **estimate** based on **observing** how fast bytes were coming in to that point. You should make sure that your code keeps updating its prediction (in a "stable" way, to avoid giving the user completely different predictions every 5 seconds).

Final note: please understand that we are not going to implement your **ideas** for you. It is your app, your vision, your product.

Comment: how to know "how much time it should take to download the remaining number of bytes"

Comment: I added an example to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: If my file in kb and my download speed 10 MB then how to get remaining duration please send me proper solution

Comment: Seriously: if you are **unable** to do that simple piece of mathematics yourself, then you should not try to do such work. And I already told you that we are **not** here to do **your** work for you.

Comment: Sorry sir i ' m beginner one day i will give answers of your question

Comment: I figured that you are a beginner. My point is: when this simple math problem is too much for you, then you are not fit to do such kind of programming. It will **not** help you when I drop some code on you. Because you have to **understand** what this code is doing; you have to add it to your code base; and you have to maintain it in the future.

Comment: @DanishKhan For the record ... if my answer did help you making progress, please consider accepting.

Comment: Hi @GhostCat, for knowing the file size, which means we have to get the file size data from server (probably via rest api), and then do calculation? Can we get total file size data while downloading a file?